# creating a hierarchy like menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with drop down menus for each item, I understand there needs to be visibility and what not in CSS but I'm unsure how to do it.

Just to be clear id want something like

---

```
Food | Houseware | Toys  
-----
Breakfast
Lunch
Dinner
Snack > Orange
        banana
        apple
```

---

```
<section id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=#> Food </a></li>
            <li><a href=#> Houseware 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=#> Breakfast </a></li>
                    <li><a href=#> Lunch </a></li>
                    <li><a href=#> Dinner </a></li>
                    <li><a href=#> Snacks </a></li>
                </ul>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href=#> Toys </a></li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

This is the code I have at the moment and it creates the bar along the top but the "Breakfast dinner lunch snacks" bit I'm guessing needed to be hidden until `:hover` is used on each particular `<li>`. I guess my round about question is am I right in putting a list within a list? If so could someone then explain the concept of what to use to make it hidden until hovered over (also if possible to make sure it snaps to the right of the drop down menu as another menu).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QuenchingTurtle/XRxxy/) This is using the answer provided first below... and it seems to push everything out of the way in a clear:both; kinda fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by BLOOD-BATH use the ">" selector to select the immediate children which will be helpful in styling the sub menu items. For eg: when you add styles to `#navbar > ul > li`, it applies the styles to the `li` items `Food, Houseware, Toys`.

To hide the sub menu items initial, make the submenu items `display:none` and on hover make them `display:block`. Use `position:absolute` on the sub menu items.

This **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/R2geF/)** might help you.

HTML

```
<section id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Food </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Houseware 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Breakfast </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Lunch </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Dinner </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Snacks </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </a></li>
        <li><a href=#> Toys </a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}

ul li{
    position:relative;
}

#navbar > ul > li{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#navbar ul ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    background-color:#fadde8;
}

#navbar ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}

#navbar ul ul ul{
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    background-color:#71efd3;
}
```

Comment: You can also add dynamic highlighting of the sub-menu items with something like: ".navbar ul li ul li:hover { background-color:#FF0000; }"

Answer (score 1):

The [> selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp) is what you need. It selects the specified children of an element, in this case the *ul* children of a *li*.

```
li>ul{
  display:none;
}
li:hover>ul{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answers, another error you made is that you failed to close the < a > tag right before the second list, also < /li > is depreciated and unnecessary for your code. if you could help me, I'm trying to make a list that instead of heading down, goes to the right, like when you are aiming for the second option on the list, but for all of the options.